# Line at end of progress of ProgressBar

Tags: android

I am new to Android Studio. I am working on my project that has a ProgressBar that should represent the result of something. I have little knowledge about progress bars.

Here is the idea of how my ProgressBar should look like:
[image: Image of ProgressBar]

Is this possible? If not, is there another way to make the progress bar transparent and only show a single line at the end of the progress of the ProgressBar?

Answer (score 0):

Create a line drawable with below code

**line.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size android:height="10dp" android:width="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

Now use this as thumb in `Seekbar` instead of `progressbar`

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:thumb="@drawable/line"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/your_layerlist_drawable"/>
```